# Using cscope with VIM: adding database returns errno 75

Tags: c, vim, vi, cscope

I've got a pretty large cscope.out database (over 2GB) and an inverted index of over 1GB, and when I issue the command `:cscope add "path to database"`, I get the following error:

```
E563: stat("path to database") error: 75
```

Looking at the source code, it seems to return the errno, where 75 means value too large for defined data type.

How can I get it to load my db?

Comment: It looks like that large db wouldn't load. So I created a cscope.files and included in it only the required files, and then rebuilt my cscope.out db. This reduced its size to less than 2GB, and that solved my issue.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that people (and machines) will know that this question has been answered.

Comment: I have the same problem. The cscope.out is > 1Gb, if I try loading it in vim I get the error "E563:stat() error:75". However, gvim loads it fine. VIM experts any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

32 bit vim imposes a 2GB limit on cscope databases. Use 64 bit vim to overcome this limitation.